# What else is described as תּוֹעֵבָה?

Tags: words, homosexuality

The prohibition of homosexual relations is described in the Torah as תּוֹעֵבָה, abomination. Is there anything else in Chumash/Chazal that is described as a תּוֹעֵבָה?

Comment: Did you try a simple search of the Torah for תועבה? What did you find lacking that you choose to ask others for help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A quick search of the Deuteronomy yields numerous examples:

- Products of idolatory (7:25-26)
- Child sacrifice (12:31)
- Inciting others to leave Judaism (13:14-15)
- Eating non-kosher animals (14:3)
- Offering blemished sacrifices (17:1)
- Worshipping idols (17:4)
- Necromancy and other forbidden forms of magic (18:12)
- Crossdressing (22:5)
- Offering a prostitute's payment as a sacrifice (23:19)
- Offering that exchanged for a dog as a sacrifice (23:19)
- Remarrying your divorcee after she had been married to someone else (24:4)
- Cheating using inaccurate weights and measures (25:17)

Another example from Halakhic literature is praying while drunk (OC 99:1).

Answer (score 8):

The best example of a  תועבה  is someone who is haughty. About such a person Scripture states (Proverbs 16:8) תועבת ה' כל גבה לב. As [R. Avraham Danzig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avraham_Danzig) points out in the introduction to Chayei Adam, this is the only case where the person, not just the act, is described as an abomination.

> וכתיב תועבת ה' כל גבה לב מה שלא מצינו כן בכל עברות שלא נאמר תועבת ה'
>   כל אוכל נבלות וטרפות וכמוהו עברות הרבה ואף שכתוב תועבה הם הינו שהדבר
>   ההוא הוא תועבה אבל לא האדם העובר נקרא תועבה

Answer (score 6):

All of the acts listed in [chapter 18](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.18?lang=en&aliyot=0) of the book of Vayikra are called “abominations” (תועבות). Like is stated clearly in [Vayikra 18:26](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.18.26?with=all&lang=bi&aliyot=0) which says:

> וּשְׁמַרְתֶּ֣ם אַתֶּ֗ם אֶת־חֻקֹּתַי֙ וְאֶת־מִשְׁפָּטַ֔י וְלֹ֣א תַעֲשׂ֔וּ מִכֹּ֥ל הַתּוֹעֵבֹ֖ת הָאֵ֑לֶּה הָֽאֶזְרָ֔ח וְהַגֵּ֖ר הַגָּ֥ר בְּתוֹכְכֶֽם׃

The term is not limited to homosexuality, although homosexuality among males is specifically described as an abomination like it says in Vayikra 18:22.

> וְאֶ֨ת־זָכָ֔ר לֹ֥א תִשְׁכַּ֖ב מִשְׁכְּבֵ֣י אִשָּׁ֑ה תּוֹעֵבָ֖ה הִֽוא׃

Comment: +1. This is certainly one of the largest and most "obvious." I think there are a few mentioned in *Kedoshim*. If I'm not mistaken, eating non-kosher animals may have that word used too?

Comment: @DanF Without getting into the details so as to avoid a firestorm here, if you examine parish Tazria carefully, you will find that what is outlined in Tazria is pointing to these abominations. There are many links. Most people assume that Tzara'at is only due to Lashon HaRa, but there seems to be a larger link to these abominations listed in Acharei Mot.

Comment: As I am unfamiliar with this connection, please provide a link on this subject for me to explore. I'm uncertain what "firestorm" could result, but, there's no need for you to clarify that if you don't care to.

Comment: @danf If it helps, the Talmud (Erkhin 16) tells us there are seven sins that cause Tzaraat: Leshon HaRa', murder, false oathes, 'Arayot, hautiness, theft, stinginess.